# shell script to kill tomcat service if it is not stopped by stop command after certain amount of time?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tomcat

I would like to write shell script to start and stop tomcat server.For stopping the tomcat I am using this command "./bin/shudown.sh" or "./bin/catalina.sh stop". This is not working most of the times, tomcat is still running.So I would like to kill the tomcat after giving shutdown command and wait for sometime(say 5min). Can anybody help me how to do it?

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`./bin/catalina.sh` should support this. If you run that command without any options, it will print out its usage, which describes:

```
stop n -force    Stop Catalina, wait up to n seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running
```

In order to make this work,  you need to set the environment variable `CATALINA_PID` to a file name that will be used to hold the Tomcat process ID. To start Tomcat, use:

```
export CATALINA_PID=/tmp/catalina.pid
./bin/catalina.sh start
```

And then to stop it:

```
export CATALINA_PID=/tmp/catalina.pid
./bin/catalina.sh stop 600 -force
```

This will try to stop it, wait for 5 minutes, then kill it if necessary. Note that this will run in the foreground by default (locking up the terminal instance); use a trailing `&` to run the command in the background.

Comment: I tried it.Tomcat is stopping now but it is not waiting for 5 minutes.It tried for stop command and if it fails it is giving kill command immediately.Here is output for command  "./bin/catalina.sh stop 600 -force"    "The stop command failed. Attempting to signal the process to stop through OS signal."
Tomcat stopped.

Comment: That message is given when catalina.sh fails to issue the `stop` command to the running instance. The comment included with that code block is `# stop failed. Shutdown port disabled? Try a normal kill.`. I can't speak to the actual motives of the Tomcat developers, but it seems that their intention is that, if the `stop` can't be issued, there is no point in waiting.

Comment: is the PID file only needed to use the -force option?

Comment: @datguy - Yes, the PID is only necessary with force (as it effectively just issues a `kill PID`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use: pkill -9 tomcatServiceName or killall -9 tomcatServiceName.

Comment: I want wait and see for sometime if it is going to stop by giving stop command.Only if it is not stopped then I would like to stop it by using kill command.